# Save N number of columns in DataGridView To SQL Table

Tags: vb.net

How to save N number of columns in  datagridview to Sql Table using VB.net

columns are not fixed and user can add columns in runtime and user should able to save data in to table

I can save the data using below codes but my problem is I need save without giving individual parameters and column names. User can add  n number of columns to datagridview in run time and those should save afer user hit the save button.

Thanks in regards

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Even_Log_Grid.Rows
    Dim SQLconstring As String = "My connection"
    Using con As New SqlConnection(SQLconstring)
        Using SQLcmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO EMP_Event_Log VALUES(@Token, @Name, @DeviceName, @PDate, @PTime)", con)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Token", row.Cells("Token No").Value)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", row.Cells("Name").Value)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeviceName", row.Cells("Device Name").Value)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PDate", CDate(row.Cells("Punch Date").Value))
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PTime", (row.Cells("Punch Time").Value))
            con.Open()
            SQLcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
         End Using
     End Using
 Next
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried and explain how it didn't work. (exceptions, unexpected results)

Comment: Sorry I re-wrote with details. If you can help  I am more great full

Comment: You say the user can add columns. I hope you mean the user can add rows. Are you getting any errors with the above code or is the database not updating?

Comment: No I mean columns. because the total hours need to divide in to separate item codes and there is a separate form to add those item codes to the grid and newly added column header text will be that item code name

Comment: You will have to add a fields clause to your SQL statement to match the values clause. How many fields are in this table?

Comment: there are 10 Fields

Answer (score 0):

I would write the insert statement with all 10 fields. Then check the existence of the column and add the values of the parameters accordingly.

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            If DataGridView1.Columns.Contains("Token No") Then
                SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Token", row.Cells("Token No").Value)
            Else
                SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Token", DBNull.Value)
            End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution. this worked for me. any way thaks for every one. Posting the codes who ever required and feel free to correct the codes if any bugs on it. Thanks & Regards,

```
For Each ROW As DataGridViewRow In Me.Review_Grid.Rows
            For I = 0 To Me.Review_Grid.Columns.Count - 1
                Dim con As New SqlConnection("My Conection String")
                Dim COM As New SqlCommand(" My Insert Command)", con)
                COM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Token", ROW.Cells("TOKEN").Value)
                COM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", ROW.Cells("NAME").Value)
                      con.Open()

                COM.ExecuteNonQuery()
                con.Close()
            Next

        Next

        MessageBox.Show("Saved Successfully", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        SQLSET.Clear()
```